# Python: How to set temporary directory location in widows

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code that will store data temporarily. In a unix like system I know of `\tmp` directory but can't figure out how to that for windows.

**Sample Code**:

```py
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    temp_directory = ''
elif os.name == 'posix':
    temp_directory = '/tmp/'
```

Do I use something like `temp_directory = '%Temp%'` ?

**Edit**:

The `gettempdir()` function from the `tempfile` module is what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use tempfile module
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: This answer is very minimal and on the edge of a link-only answer. Either edit it to be more complete as described in [answer], or simply delete it as there are already many answers suggesting the same in the different duplicate targets around